# I have uploaded the files of my website in cpanel in public_html but after that website is not visible on web

Tags: hosting, cpanel

I have uploaded my website files to public_html in cpanel 11 but even after that my website will not display online. When I type in the domain name, the site is  redirected to some ww2."my domain name" .

Comment: Have you contacted your host?

Comment: not yet. I have understood that my original domain name is not integrated to hosting. if I use direct url then the website is live or else it is not. Thank you for such quick response

Comment: This is by no means a programming question. And hence, it has nothing to do on StackOverflow. Please migrate to SuperUser, or even better yet, contact the people you pay to give you support.

Comment: I thought since there are tags of web hosting shared hosting etc, I could post it here. I didn't hope that it would be a trouble to someone. My apologies if it was so.

Answer (score 0):

you could make - telnet "yourdomainname" 80, and after that "GET / HTTP/1.1" to see what will be the response code, and if there are some redirects.

Comment: This is the response                                                                    HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 18 Jun 2015 19:41:46 GMT
Server: Apache Phusion_Passenger/4.0.10 mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_fcgid/2.3.9
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

Comment: Check what is the default document in your cPanel settings. (by example index.php etc...) it seems as you have not default document set.

Comment: Actually I have a Comodo SSL certificate which is yet to be verified. Is that creating any trouble?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make sure following things:

- Make sure that your domain is resolving correct IP address. If it is not resolving to your hosting server, contact your host for further assistance.
- Make sure that you have uploaded the contents to proper directory. You may ask your host if you have any doubt in your hosting control panel.